# ¿Cuál es el origen de la frase "media naranja"?

Tags: definiciones, modismos

## Español

He oído la frase "media naranja" unas veces, y puedo entender el contexto, que significa una pareja o novia, por ejemplo. Pero quiero saber el origen de esa frase.

## English

I have heard the phrase "media naranja" some times, and I can understand the context, it means a girlfriend/boyofriend, for example. But I want to know the origin of this expression.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Viene de [un mito de la antigua Grecia](http://www.sabiask.com/sabiasque/historia/origen-de-la-expresion-media-naranja.html).

Un extracto del enlace:

> Contaba Aristófanes que, en un principio, la raza humana era casi perfecta. Los seres eran esféricos como naranjas; tenían dos caras opuestas sobre una misma cabeza, cuatro brazos y cuatro piernas que utilizaban para desplazarse rodando. 
>   [...]
>
> Zeus los castigó partiéndolos por la mitad con el rayo; y mandó a Hermes que a cada uno le atara la carne sobrante en torno al ombligo. [...]
>
> Zeus, compadecido por la estirpe humana, ordenó a Hermes que les girase la cara hacia el mismo lado donde tenían el sexo: de este modo, cada vez que uno de estos seres encontrara a su otra mitad, de esa unión pudiera obtener placer y si además se trataba de un ser andrógino pudieran tener descendencia. [...]
>
> Desde entonces los seres humanos nos vemos condenados a buscar entre nuestros semejantes a nuestra media naranja con la que unirnos en abrazos que nos hagan más "completos".

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE!  Y gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @Flimzy La historia de los humanos esféricos es contada en [“El banquete,” también conocido por “El simposio,” de Platón.](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/El_banquete) Pero no hay una sola referencia a naranjas en “El banquete.” ¿Cómo podría haberla? Las [naranjas fueron introducidas en Europa más de 1000 años después que la historia fue escribida.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naranja)

Comment: @jacinto: Seguramente la idea esencial proviene de ese mito, pero estoy de acuerdo con tus dudas... La pregunta sigue sin respuesta:  Por que naranjas precisamente?  Por que no otra fruta esferica como el limon u otra cosa esferica que se puede partir?