# ¿Se puede usar "granada" como un término de cariño?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

Ya he oído palabras como "amor", "cariño/a", "cielo", "corazón", etcétera, para describirse un objeto de interés amoroso, pero ¿hay otros términos de cariño?

Por ejemplo, ¿se puede llamar a una novia o esposa "granada", como en la fruta de la pasión? ¿O suena mal? Ya he buscado pero no encontré una respuesta.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Hay una cosa que no me queda clara: ¿dices "granada" por decir una palabra cualquiera? ¿O es que lo has oído usado como término de cariño en alguna parte?

Comment: A mí me sonaría a esto: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/90/bc/19/90bc1947b45c384048ec7007c8a74d11.jpg

Comment: *Granado, da: 1. adj. Notable y señalado, principal, ilustre y escogido.
2. adj. Maduro, juicioso.* No esta la respuesta que buscas en la RAE, y personalmente no la usaría.

Comment: Un apunte, aunque existe ["cariña"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7Za5ccs), creo que tiene un significado completamente distinto a "cariño", término que se usa para ambos sexos.

Comment: Buscando alguna fruta que signifique "cariño" encontré solo esto. Parece ser que en Centroamérica _**mango**_ significa "atractivo", y en Perú _**zapallo**_ significa "avispado" (ambas son frutas americanas). No encontré otros requiebros frutales. En cambio hay varios _vegetales-insulto_, sobre todo para decir "tonto": _**breva**_ (Chile), _**zanahoria**_ (Argentina), _**nabo**_ (Uruguay), _**banano**_ (Nicaragua) y _**coco**_ (Puerto Rico). En Venezuela _**piña**_ es "fastidioso". Y parece que en España _**coco**_ es "feo" (aunque no creo que por la fruta sino por el diablo).

Comment: Te recomiendo esta expresión: *corazón de melón.*

Comment: Ya que hablas de "fruta de la pasión": [¿Es correcto usar la expresión “fruta de la pasión”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17563/12637)

Answer (score 3):

> ¿se puede llamar a una novia o esposa "granada", como en la fruta de la pasión?

No. En inglés "pumpkin" puede ser un *term of endearment* pero en español no vas a oír mucho "calabaza" o "calabacita" (a menos que sea en lugares con fuertes influencias de la lengua aglosajona) y mucho menos vas a oír "granada".

Puedes decir que alguien es una "perita en dulce" (una mujer joven y hermosa) o que alguien es "[tu media naranja](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3218/5481)" pero no por ello se puede usar cualquier fruta para apelativos cariñosos. Decirle a alguien que es "un melón" es llamarle obtuso o testarudo. No vas a oír usar "granada" como apelativo cariñoso.

> ¿hay otros términos de cariño?

Como sabes, entre otros muchos tenemos:

- (mi) cielo
- (mi) amor
- cariño
- tesoro
- (mi) vida / vida mía
- mi alma (aunque este se usa menos como cariñoso y a veces como más condescendiente)

Pero no vas a encontrar "términos cariñosos relacionados con frutas" o "animales" (aunque puedas decirle a alguien "gatita") o similar. Los términos cariñosos suelen guardar relación con los de la lista de arriba por razones obvias: expresan cosas muy queridas o valiosas o directamente se refieren a términos amorosos.

Answer (score 1):

A ver, como poder, poder, puedes. Siempre que cuentes con el contexto adecuado. No creo que sea la respuesta que buscas, pero en realidad cualquier palabra del español puede ser usada como término de cariño siempre que cuentes con un trasfondo. Eso sí, yo procuraría usar algún diminutivo como "granadita".

Me explico: "granada" de por sí no es una palabra de cariño. Pero si, por ejemplo, estás escribiendo un relato, te puedes inventar una historia de amor entre dos personajes: ponle que uno de los dos es amante de las armas de fuego y tiene un carácter explosivo. Puedes hacer que el otro le llame "mi granadita", dado que ya tienes el contexto adecuado y el lector lo va a entender. Pero desde luego, sin un contexto nadie va a entender "granada" como palabra de cariño.

Y para quien se pregunte cómo se me ha ocurrido el ejemplo: hay un manga de Kenichi Sonoda titulado [Gunsmith Cats](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunsmith_Cats) en el que una de las protagonistas es una experta en explosivos a la que le pone el olor a pólvora.

Sí, ya sé que no es el tipo de "granada" planteado en la pregunta...

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión como las anteriores,  el uso es posible pero no es común y suelen ir acompañados de un diminutivo. En ocasiones he podido escuchar "pomelito/a" y algunos más

Comment: Sí, con un diminutivo puedes usar casi cualquier palabra.