# Tener suerte de/en

Tags: gramática

Quisiera saber si se puede decir "tener suerte en" en vez de "tener suerte de". Por ejemplo, "tener suerte en encontrar su media naranja ideal" en vez de "tener suerte de encontrar su media naranja ideal". ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que la rae dice que se puede o no incluir la preposición "(a) su" en algunos casos y en otros agregar "en" o "de" dependiendo de la región o la simultaneidad con otro evento por lo tanto sería mejor que lo conjugaras en algún tiempo y la persona como en "tuvo suerte de haber encontrado a su" o "tuvo la suerte de encontrar a su", sin mencionar que "de" es la más usada o reconocida y "en" tiene un uso temporal o es una traducción del inglés "in" o de "to have", como sea, para mi son casi iguales o por lo menos es aceptada y muy usada la última por acá. pd. Justo te respondieron.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone like me who was confused about why Maurice was looking for an orange stocking the phrase _media naranja_ has been explained https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-origen-de-la-frase-media-naranja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando el verbo es télico, es decir, que implica la obtención de un objetivo puntual y concreto, lo correcto es decir:

- tener suerte de + infinitivo

Ej. Espero **tener suerte de encontrar** mi media naranja.

Con verbos atélicos, puede llegar a funcionar "en" para introducir una situación más que un hecho:

Ej. **Tiene suerte en tener** a quien recurrir.

Lo que es claro es que, cuando se dice "la suerte", se requiere "de":

Ej. **Tiene la suerte de tener** a quien recurrir.

Además, con sustantivos se usa "en":

Ej. **tener suerte en la lotería**

Nota: "Media naranja ideal" es redundante. La "media naranja" es la pareja ideal.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!